# bash exec redirection equivalent in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

What's PowerShell equivalent of `exec` redirection in bash like this?

```sh
exec 2>&1
```

I wanted to make a PowerShell script to redirect its stderr to stdout by itself, without any function or script block calls [like this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection#example-3-send-success-warning-and-error-streams-to-a-file), or recursive script invocation.

The redirection should occur in the beginning of the script, then all stderr output from the rest of the script and sub-process should go to stdout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't: Unlike Bash, **PowerShell has *no* feature for script-wide redirection of streams** (as of PowerShell v7).

You'll have to do one of the very things you're trying to avoid:

- Enclose all code in your script in `. { ... } 2>&1`
- Recursively invoke your script via such an enclosure (which requires some mechanism, such as a conceptually private parameter, to prevent infinite recursion).

Also note that while stdout and stderr are the *conceptual* equivalents of PowerShell's success output stream and error stream, respectively:

- PowerShell has *6* output streams in total - see [`about_Redirection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection) (which your question already links to).
- Regrettably, *all* of these streams are by default mapped to *stdout* when PowerShell is called from the outside, via its CLI.

  - However, you can *selectively* redirect the *error stream* using `2>`  from the outside - but none of the other streams, aside from the success stream.

Answer (score -2):

There's no "exec" in powershell (overlaying a process).  But redirecting stderr to stdout is the same:

```
 yourscript.ps1 2>&1
```

If you were running pwsh from some other unix shell, or powershell from cmd in windows, everything would go to stdout anyway:

```
pwsh yourscript.ps1 > yourscript.log
```

Don't worry about marking me down.  Other people will mark me up later.  I'm used to it.

Comment: Do you know about the effect of `exec` with redirection in bash?

Comment: I don't think there's something like exec in powershell.

Comment: Why don't you run `myscript.ps1 2>&1`?

Comment: Also, if you run powershell from bash, it all goes to standard out anyway.

Comment: Again, do you know `exec` builtin syntax without any command to execute but with redirection in bash?  It executes nothing but changes redirection of the current shell, which enables scripts to redirect their I/O by themselves without any additional process/function/statement construct inside/outside.  I just asked if PowerShell had an equivalent feature of this.

Comment: Yes.  There isn't.